# Appending handlebars content in google maps infowindow

Tags: google-maps, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a google maps infowindow, into which i want to append a string rendered from a Handlebars template. Currently i am using:

```
marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: '<h5>' + '<b>' + self.get('i18n').t('apiary.new_title').string + ': </b>' + '</h5>'+
                  '<div id="bodyContent">'+ Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div class="form-group"> {{input value=name type="text" placeholder="Apiary Name" class="form-control"}} </div>') + 
                  '</div>',
              options: {
                maxWidth: 200
              }
            });
```

However the compile results into an Object and not a string. Is it possible to compile into a string and of course keep the value always bound when the user changes the form ?

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars templates compile into a function (which is an object, but a special kind of object), that you then execute with some context (the information you want to land in the curly braces you put in your template) as the argument to the function:

```
var template = '<div class="form-group"> <input value={{name}} type="text" placeholder="Apiary Name" class="form-control"/> </div>'

var context = {name: 'Bob Johnson'};

var compiledTemplate = Ember.Handlebars.compile(template);

var templatedData = compileTemplate(context);

marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<h5>' + '<b>' + 
        self.get('i18n').t('apiary.new_title').string + 
        ': </b>' + '</h5>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">' + 
        templatedData + '</div>',
    options: {
        maxWidth: 200
    }
});
```

Note that I've modified your template in this example because I don't think you want the entire `<input/>` tag to be a template context variable, I think you just want the `value` attribute of that element to be the template context variable.

So yes, this is totally doable, and not at all undesirable, you are simply missing the part where you execute the function that the Handlebars compilation step returned.  Since you are using Ember, I believe you will get bindings out of this, or at least I know that's possible with Ember, but I'm not an Ember expert.